# Тире вместо двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Подготовил рекламу одного устройства. Написал его отличительные черты:
**Инновации — первый коммерческий спектрометр с функциями Помощника...** и т. д.
**Точность — новейшая соударительная ячейка обеспечивает высокую чувствительность** и т. д.
Редактор ответила, что нужно обязательно заменить тире на двоеточие. Тире в этом случае нельзя использовать?
Буду благодарен за любой ответ.

Comment: Поскольку это не определения, а черты, действительно, вроде тире не подходит. Мне кажется, как раз двоеточие и нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Редактор права: здесь необходимо двоеточие. Вот что говорится в справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя.

Двоеточие ставится в заголовках, распадающихся на две части с четким интонационным делением, отличающиеся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью, нередко и эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет общую проблему, место действия, лицо, а вторая — содержит конкретизацию названного в первой части:

> Экономическая реформа: опыт, проблемы, трудности; Разоружение: концепция, проблемы, механизм; Россия — Западная Европа: выгоды и перспективы сотрудничества; Звёздный рейс: работа на отлично!; Новый герой: поиски и находки; Женщина: семья и работа; Юпитер: планета или звезда?; Перевозка айсбергов: мифы и реальность; Смена правительства: старое наследство, новые возможности; Генетика: стратегия и тактика; Космические лучи: старые или новые?; Энергетика: начало и будущее; Многоэтажные улицы: спасение или бедствие?; Рентгеновский лазер: поиски и надежды.

Тире ставится в следующих случаях:

Тире ставится в эллиптических предложениях-заголовках, построенных по формуле «кому-чему — что» или «что — кому — чему» (см. § 6, п. 3): **Выпускнику — профессию; Новому — широкую дорогу; Транспорту — чёткость и слаженность; Достижения науки — в производство; Имя Гагарина — малой планете; Награды — лучшим; Музыка — детям.**

2. Тире ставится в двучленных предложениях-заголовках, построенных по формулам «кто — чему», «кто — куда», «что — куда», «что — где», «что — как», «что — для чего» и т. д. (см. § 6, п. 4): **Учёные — производству; Клоуны — на арену; Книгу — в массы; Передовую технологию — в производство; Учителя — в отпуске; Ракета — на орбите; Строить — быстро.**

Ср. заголовки другой структуры: **Задание десяти месяцев — выполнено; В город — на праздник книги; За опытом — к соседям; В час — тысяча саженцев; На линии — 115 городов; Главные задачи — впереди; По ступеням — к высотам знаний; За преступление — к ответу.**

3. Тире ставится в заголовках, построенных по схеме «подлежащее — сказуемое» без связки (что отвечает об щей норме; см. § 5, п. 1): **Герои фильмов — дети; Курс — интенсификация; Автор — студент; Девиз соревнований — скорость; Технические средства — помощники учителя.**
4. Тире ставится в заголовках, состоящих из нескольких форм именительного падежа (номинативов): **Зима — снег — лыжи; Школа — жизнь — труд.**

Answer (score 0):

У вашего редактора виден опыт работы с английскими тестами. Там двоеточие ставить любят и нас этому научили. Особенно в заголовках книг. Конечно, здесь двоеточие выглядит логичнее, потому что первое слово как бы раскрывает сжато то, что идёт после него. Двоеточие здесь выглядит как дверь в новую реальность.